# Dynamic multiple criteria on sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I was thinking of this for 3 days now. There is a formula that will do this, but I can't figure it out. Hope someone can help me on this.

I'm trying to sum a column in the spreadsheet based on several conditions:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     ID4     Value
SW       A       1       X        4
SW       B       2       Y        5
SE       C       2       Y        6
SE       A       2       X        3
NE       A       0       X        2
SE       A       1       X        3
```

I would like to sum the value column based on the following conditions:

```
ID1 = SW, SE
ID2 = A, C
ID3 = 1, 0
ID4 = X, Y
```

Based on the conditions above, sum should be 7

Seems `Sumif(s)` can only handle 1 dynamic multiple criteria and once I loaded the criteria of `ID2`, only SW of ID were totaled, formula excluded the SE. (In below formula, ID4 criteria was not yet included).

```
=SUMIFS(RawData!G:G,RawData!$D:$D,IF($B$7="","<>",{"SW","SE"}),RawData!$C:$C,$C21,RawData!$E:$E,IF($B$9="","<>",{"A","C"}),RawData!$F:$F,IF($B$10="","<>",{"1","0"}))
```

Is there any way it can handle multiple criteria which in each criteria is an array? Thanks!

Comment: `IF($B$7="","<>",{"SW","SE"})` this bit doesn't look right.

Comment: I'd do this with sumproduct. Sorry don't have time to write up an example... Maybe later if it is still open.

Comment: @SJR `IF($B$7="","<>",{"SW","SE"})` actually this is when the user doesn't select/pick any on the ID1 (it will show all). `Cell` B7 is actually linked to a multi select `ListBox` form control. I only manually put SW and SE there to show the current issue.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't realise "<>" was an acceptable parameter. It does appear that this should work. You can wait for RIchard. An alternative approach would be AutoFilter and sum the visible cells in Value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SUMIFS` can handle up to **two** criteria lists, (assuming you want to count all possible combinations) as long as one is a "row" and one is a "column" (or transposed to be so), e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Sumrange,Critrange1,{"x","y"},Critrange2,{"a";"b"}))`

Note that {"x","y"} has a comma separator (a row) while {"a";"b"} has semi-colon (a column), it has to be like that

`SUMIFS` produces an array of 4 values (all possible combinations) so `SUMPRODUCT` is used to sum those 4 values. For 3 or more criteria lists use `SUMPRODUCT` with `MATCH`, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(Sumrange,ISNUMBER(MATCH(Critrange1,{"SW","SE"},0)*MATCH(Critrange2,{"A","C"},0)*MATCH(Critrange3,{1,0},0)*MATCH(Critrange4,{"X","Y"},0))+0)`

Where all ranges are the same dimensions

Your `IF` functions on the criteria complicate this, and are more difficult to accommodate in this type of formula, but you can cater for those like this, assuming that when the relevant cell is blank all non-blanks are counted:

`=SUMPRODUCT(((B7="")*(Critrange1<>"")+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Critrange1,{"SW","SE"},0))>0)*((B8="")*(Critrange2<>"")+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Critrange2,{"A","C"}0))>0)*((B9="")*(Critrange3<>"")+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Critrange3,{1,0}0))>0)*((B10="")*(Critrange4<>"")+ISNUMBER(MATCH(Critrange4,{"x","y"}0))>0))`

Note for {1,0} match in this formula only numeric values will be matched. If the data is text formatted quotes need to be added, e.g. `{"1","0"}` - this works differently in SUMIFS where you can use quotes or not and it will count both text and numbers

In this version you can use commas or semi-colons in the `MATCH` functions, as long as you are consistent within each `MATCH`

Comment: Hey barry, thanks for the above! follow up question, I was thinking that if the user didn't select anything, it should show all for that particular criteria. Does we have an option for All in `MATCH`? Like in `SUMIFS`, we just need to put `"<>"`

Comment: I just added something in for that - more difficult to do in SUMPRODUCT.....see edited version above